# HTML drag drop from one div to other

Tags: html

```
<script>function allowDrop(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();}function drag(ev) {
ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);}    function drop(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));}</script>
```

script section above add !DOCTYPE HTML html head style between the head. Body below

```
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="drag1" class="drag2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">Aa</div>
```

Is this correct way to implement drag drop?

Comment: You are not asking any actual question here so far. Please go read [ask], and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a `span` tag and copy `inner text` and use it. Please have a look into code snippet.

```css
#div1 { 
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-box;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

#drag1 { 
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-box;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<body>


<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<div id="drag1" class="drag2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">Aa</div>


<script>

function allowDrop(ev) 
{
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) 
{
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) 
{
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    var copyTxt = document.createElement("span");
    var original = document.getElementById(data);
    var text = original.textContent || original.innerText;
    copyTxt.innerText =  text;
    ev.target.appendChild(copyTxt);
}
</script>
</body>
```